# Trying to use a SELECT command on the result of another SELECT command

Tags: mysql

I used this syntax to join data from one table to another based on date:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Incident_DateCopy), wt.dt_iso, weather_main
  FROM `incidentdatatwo` 
  LEFT 
  JOIN `weather` AS wt 
    ON DATE(dt_iso) = Incident_DateCopy
```

Now, I need to count and group the result by the `weather_main` column. Tried the following but it won't work:

```
SELECT `weather_main`
     , COUNT(*) 
  FROM `incidentdatatwo` 
   (SELECT DISTINCT(Incident_DateCopy)
             , wt.dt_iso
             , weather_main 
        FROM `incidentdatatwo` 
        LEFT 
        JOIN `weather` AS wt 
           ON DATE(dt_iso) = Incident_DateCopy) 
     GROUP 
         BY weather_main;
```

Comment: Distinct is not a function. I would suggest you start over, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You're missing a `JOIN` there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
SELECT 
    weather_main,COUNT(*) 
FROM  
(SELECT DISTINCT(Incident_DateCopy), wt.dt_iso, weather_main 
FROM incidentdatatwo 
LEFT JOIN weather AS wt ON DATE(dt_iso) = Incident_DateCopy) a1
GROUP BY weather_main;
```

But

```
SELECT  weather_main,COUNT(*)
FROM incidentdatatwo 
LEFT JOIN weather AS wt ON DATE(dt_iso) = Incident_DateCopy
GROUP BY weather_main;
```

Is enough to get the count